# julia - How to refactor a utils.jl file

Tags: julia

I have a utils.jl file in my main project that I want to refactor out into the MyProjectBase.jl package.

I normally do a `include("utils.jl")` in the MyProject.jl module which lets me use it in all my project files.

But if I refactor it out now I have to do `using MyProjectBase` in every file that uses utils.jl methods.

How do I make it so I don't have to do the using in every file?

Comment: Create a package with the code of utils and in the old file utils jl write "using MyProjectBasis". By the way, if you were including the same file multiple times you had a problem, the output may not be the one you do expect.

Comment: including multiple times no.  so a simple using at the beginning of the root project module will make the utils available for all project files?